# joomla component: how to remove all the preloaded data and css

Tags: joomla2.5, custom-component

alright folks,
this is hwta am trying to do. I have a joomla component that i have installed. It works very well but now i want the component to load its own index.php and css without having to rely or care about the default template.i have created one component/views/dafault.php and in it called

require_once ('D:\site\localsite\templates\component\index.php');

in the index.php i have already called the css so this is ok. The problem is all the other default items are coming into the view the top menu, the side menu the logos and everything else of the default template.

please assist me. im pulling ma hair on this one. and im new to joomla - was used  to kohana.

and yaa i have tried tmpl=component and its not doing much. is there a way to stripe away everything that preloads for example on the default template and leave only the component staff?

Comment: the background of this is that am developing a component for a huge organisation that has many components and the component should not interfere with the rest of the sites/components.

Comment: You would probably do better to make a stripped down template and assign it to your component using the template manager

Comment: i already have a stripped down template for this. the issue is the other links in the component. the link i make a menu for renders correct bu the other link like index.php?option=com_component&task=foo.bar renders in the default template

Comment: OK i have noticed if i do this index.php?option=com_component&task=foo.bar&template=comtemplate then the views are rendered with the correct component. this is what i wanted although this is still a longer way. i still don't have a more superior way because if a user removes the template=contemplate from the url then they get the default template.

Comment: Yeah, the way that Joomla is setup, you can only assign a template to the menu. You could add a redirect in the base of your component to redirect to the same url but with the template addition. I'll add an answer with code for that.

Comment: that will be interesting.i will also think of the same. let me know if you get an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the base file of your component (located at `components/com_yourname/yourname.php`) you would want to do a check for the component being set and then set it (or redirect to a url that sets it) if not set:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$jinput = $app->input;
// check if they are on the default menu item (i.e. not your component's)
// also check if the template is set already
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault() && $jinput->get('template') != 'comtemplate') {
    // you might be able to get away with this, I haven't tested this
    $jinput->set('template', 'comtemplate');
    // otherwise set up a redirect
    // get the current url of the page
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // check if '?' already exists in the url
    // if it does then there is already the start of the query string so we should
    // use '&' to tack on the new query item
    // if not then start the query string with '?'
    $url .= (strpos($url, '?')===FALSE ? '?' : '&') . 'template=comtemplate';
    // take the new url and redirect to it.
    //This should update the url in the browser for the user
    $app->redirect($url);
    // since you redirected, no sense letting anything else run here, so exit
    exit();
}
```

UPDATE: I added better comments in the code so hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hey David, Thatnks for this super code but its not working though, im trying to see  $url = JURI::current();
    $url .= (strpos($url, '?')===FALSE ? '?' : '&') . 'template=comtemplate';
    $app->redirect($url);
    exit(); does but this is giving the URL and if i specify any class it truncates the class and appends the template=comtemplte...lol

Comment: Can you give me an example of the url that you type in and then what it directs you to at the end?

Comment: Thanks for the better code. I will try it in the evening and let you know. For example if i try this. localhost/jooms/index.php?option=comcomponent&task=foo.bar i get something like this. locahost/jooms/index.php?template=comtemplate but that is after i tried to play with the code you had given earlier.

Comment: I have to apologize, `JURI::current()` was not returning the full url like I thought, so it was leaving off the query string. Updated the answer to the standard php method which should work.

Comment: Hey David, Still this is not giving the desired output. There is nothing outputting. the key problem is i cant troubleshoot the code.maybe you can tell me where exactly to put it. i'm putting it right after jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
$controller = JController::getInstance('mycomponent');
$controller->execute( JRequest::getCmd('task') );
$controller->redirect(); thanks so far for your input.

Comment: You need to put it above all that actually. This should run before you execute the task.

Comment: Hey David, Sorry for the update above. I have tried the code one more time and it has worked like a charm. i Just removed "$menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault() &&" and it worked perfectly.Now i have taken it and put it in a function in a helper and i just call this function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome. That check was to see if the current menu item matched the default (likely meaning that there was no `Itemid` set with the url). This was probably an unnecessary check but I thought it would help. Sorry it slowed you down a bit!

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't understand your question wrong, you can do something like this;

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'position-1' )) : ?>
   <div class="cssforthecomponent">
      <jdoc:include type="component" />
   </div>
<?php else: ?>  

<?php if ($this->countModules( 'position-2' )) : ?>
    <div class="cssfortherestofwebsite">
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Assign the component to a menu item with an empty module to position-1 for the same menu item. It will work. You don't need to include or do etc. stuff for that.

Peace..

Answer (score 0):

you can call your component this way :

```
index.php?option=com_your_component&format=raw
```

or you can add a menu item for your component and disable all module assignements for this menu item

Comment: when i try this i get  the following Invalid controller: name='union', format='raw'

Comment: im using index.php?option=com_your_component&template=comtemplate for every url. but is there another superior way?

Answer (score 0):

You are working way too hard on this. Joomla is designed to make template overrides easy to do without hard coding a bunch of stuff that could potentially cause issues later. The easiest way to do it would be to create a template specific for this component, then assign that template to this component only. You will need to create a menu item for the component so you have an item ID and it shows up in the menu assignment in the template manager. If the template is similar to the original site template you can made a duplicate in the template manager then edit the resulting copy.

Comment: i have tried this, created a menu and assigned that menu to this template but its not working. i have to research on this some more to get it right. But what i was thinking is that the only thing i want is for the component to be rendered with nothing from the main template. then i can add my template with the require once or include

Comment: This is a basic Joomla function. If the template is not being used for the menu item then you have something else going wrong. Can you assign a template to another component? If so, the problem is with your component.